# Templates :Name resolution -->IS this statement is true while inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates, token-name-resolution

This is the statement from ISO C++ Standard 14.6/6:

> Within the definition of a class template or within the definition of a member of a class template, the keyword `typename` is not required when referring to the unqualified name of a previously declared member of the class template that declares a type. The keyword `typename` shall always be specified when the member is referred to using a qualified name, even if the qualifier is simply the class template name. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
>     typedef int B;
>     A::B b;             // ill-formed: typename required before A::B
>     void f(A<T>::B);    // ill-formed: typename required before A<T>::B
>     typename A::B g();  // OK
> };
> ```
>
> The keyword typename is required whether the qualified name is `A` or `A<T>` because `A` or `A<T>` are synonyms within a class template with the parameter list `<T>`. ]

Is this statement is true while inheritance?

If yes, can anyone explain this?

I checked with inner class; it is accepted? But I am unable to check with inheritance?

Comment: Perhaps you can expand on your question with a few examples; I don't think it's very clear as stated (I certainly don't understand what you are asking).  (Also, I think your comments in the cited text may be on the wrong lines; they don't make sense where they are currently placed.  I don't have a PDF of the standard handy to check).

Comment: ISO/IECINTERNATIONAL STANDARD             14882

                                   Second edition
                                   2003-10-15
Programming languages — C++
Langages de programmation — C++

Comment: @BES: I guess you tried to post a link but couldn't because you don't have enough points. That's a good thing, because pirating the standard on this site would be uncool.

Comment: Why do you always think that everything is the standard is wronge, false, ... ?

Comment: Without even looking at the statement: __Yes, of course it's true!__ That's the _C++ standard_; with the exception of a few defects (most of which were likely found during the decade the standard has been out there), whatever it says is the truth _by definition_.

Comment: @sbi,@Cedric H,@Potatoswatter : Iam not finding faults in standard..iam finding faults in compilers...whether they are following the standard or not....that is my thesis.......For that iam trying in many forms of test...But iam unable write the program for some statements..thats why ask help here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is equally true of inherited members.

The keyword `typename` is required for members of base *templates*, but not base classes in general. The reason it is required for base templates is that their members are not automatically brought into the scope of the `class {}` block, so the only way to refer to them is with a qualified-id, which requires `typename`.

```
template< typename >
class base1
    { typedef int type1; };

class base2 
    { typedef int type2; };

template< typename A >
class derived
    : base1< A >, base2 {
    typename base1< A >::type1 x;
    type2 y;
};
```